# Redirect User to another url with django-allauth log in signal

Tags: django, django-signals, django-allauth

I am using Django-allauth for my login/signup related stuff, so when a user signs up(first time) into my site, I am redirecting him to `/thanks/` page by defining below setting in `settings.py` file

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/thanks/'

But when the user tried to log in for the next time(if already registered) I should redirect him to `'/dashboard/'` URL

So tried to alter that with `Django-allauth signals` like below which is not working at all

```
@receiver(allauth.account.signals.user_logged_in)
def registered_user_login(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(kwargs['user'])
    print instance.last_login==instance.date_joined,"??????????????????????????????"
    if not instance.last_login==instance.date_joined:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

So can anyone please let me know how to redirect a user to `/dashboard/` for the normal login, am I doing anything wrong in the above signal code?

**Edit**

After some modification according to the below answer by `pennersr`, my `AccountAdapter` class looks like below

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

  def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
    if request.user.last_login == request.user.date_joined:
        return '/registration/success/'
    else:
        return '/dashboard/'
```

But still, it is redirecting the user to `/dashboard/`, my logic in determining the first time user is wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In general, you should not try to put such logic in a signal handler. What if there are multiple handlers that want to steer in different directions?

Instead, do this:

```
# settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.users.allauth.AccountAdapter'


# project/users/allauth.py:
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

  def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
      return '/some/url/'
```

Comment: Thanks pennersr, i had edited my anser above, can u please help me out with that ?

Comment: Also can we able to provide user an option to resend the confirmation email ? if not confirmed when he has registered ?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the values of last_login/date_joined? Resending confirmation emails happens automatically, as soon as the user tries to login with an unverified e-mail. Note that in order to prevent mail bombardments this only kicks in when the login attempts are 3 minutes or so apart.

Comment: Do not name the new file 'project/.../allauth.py' it will then load first in your path and mask the entire allauth library throwing an ImportError.

Comment: @pennersr would you not mind to help me on issue listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885732/allauth-redirect-to-custom-form-page-before-successful-signup

Answer (score 9):

The two datetimes `last_login` and `date_joined` will always be different, although it might only be a few milliseconds. This snippet works:

```
# settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'yourapp.adapter.AccountAdapter'

# yourapp/adapter.py:
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        threshold = 90 #seconds

        assert request.user.is_authenticated()
        if (request.user.last_login - request.user.date_joined).seconds < threshold:
            url = '/registration/success'
        else:
            url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        return resolve_url(url)
```

One **important remark** to pennersr answer: **AVOID** using files named **allauth.py** as it will confuse Django and lead to **import errors**.

Comment: @user2292376 I think the `assert` is unnecessary here, as this is a login redirect, so the user is supposed to be authenticated at the point this is called. However, +1

Comment: @DH1TW i believe this solution is not entirely bullet proof... i just realized that if a user attempts a failed login (wrong password) the request.user.last_login still gets updated for some reason, so request.user.last_login != request.user.date_joined and not even the threshold can save it.. do you guys have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

the answer here is very simple, you do not need any signals or overriding the `DefaultAccountAdapter`
in `settings.py` just add a signup redirect_url

```py
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = "/thanks/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/dashboard/"
```

Comment: this should really be the accepted answer, I think the others are very old. allauth correctly respects standard django settings, no need for special classes that reimplement framework functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define those two other signals using **user_logged_in** signal as base. A good place to put it is on a **signals.py** inside a **accounts** app, in case you have one, or in you **core** app. Just remember to import **signals.py** in you **__init__.py**.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver, Signal

pre_user_first_login = Signal(providing_args=['request', 'user'])
post_user_first_login = Signal(providing_args=['request', 'user'])


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def handle_user_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    first_login = user.last_login is None
    if first_login:
        pre_user_first_login.send(sender, user=user, request=request)
    print 'user_logged_in'
    if first_login:
        post_user_first_login.send(sender, user=user, request=request)


@receiver(pre_user_first_login)
def handle_pre_user_first_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print 'pre_user_first_login'


@receiver(post_user_first_login)
def handle_post_user_first_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print 'post_user_first_login'
```

Comment: Note: `providing_args` may no longer be included as an argument in `Signal()`